# After hiding div allow to redisplay on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

The initial display is to only have the first div displaying. When you select Add Another, the next div will display as well. When you select "Remove" next to that div it will be hidden/removed.

The problem I am having is how to get the div to redisplay if the user selects Add Another. So that they can have a max of 4 divs displaying. Currently after selecting "Remove" if you select "Add Another" it will only display a div if it has not been displayed and removed previously.
I would like the user to always have the option of adding all 4 divs even if they were to add one then remove it and then would like to add it back.

Here is my current code:

```js
//Remove div when clicked  
$('#donation_element1_row').show();
$('.removeDiv').click( function() {
    $(this).closest('div[id*="donation_element"]').hide();
});
//Add another designation
var count = 0,
$allDivs = $('#donation_element2_row, #donation_element3_row, #donation_element4_row');
$('#addAnother').click( function() {
    if( count < $allDivs.length ) {
        $allDivs.eq( count ).fadeIn( 'slow' );
        count++;
    }
});
```

```css
#addAnother {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 236px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 44px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #f8a61b;
    color: #860005;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f8a61b;
}

div[id*='donation_element'] {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    margin: 10px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
.removeDiv {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="donation_element1_row">
    <p>Div 1</p>
    <div class="removeDiv">Remove X</div>
</div>
<div id="donation_element2_row">
    <p>Div 2</p>
    <div class="removeDiv">Remove X</div>
</div>
<div id="donation_element3_row">
    <p>Div 3</p>
    <div class="removeDiv">Remove X</div>
</div>
<div id="donation_element4_row">
    <p>Div 4</p>
    <div class="removeDiv">Remove X</div>
</div>
<div id="addAnother">+ Add Another</div>
```

Comment: You really could use classes for your *donation*...

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/km1je4th/ (using `$allDivs.filter(":hidden").eq(0).show();`)

Comment: You may also want to hide the "Add Another" button when the fourth donation row is added (in the add function), and show it when the length is under four (in the remove function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the below code. So when you delete the div, append it to the end. This will help you for more than 4 divs.

```js
//Remove div when clicked  
$('#donation_element1_row').show();

$('.removeDiv').click( function() {
 $(this).parent().hide();
  $("#parent_donation_container").append($(this).parent());
});

$('#addAnother').click( function() {    
    $(".donation_element").not(":visible").first().fadeIn( 'slow' );
});
```

```css
#addAnother {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 236px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 44px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #f8a61b;
    color: #860005;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f8a61b;
}

div[id*='donation_element'] {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;

  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 200px;
  }
  
  .removeDiv {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    }
p {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent_donation_container">
    <div id="donation_element1_row" class="donation_element"><p>
    Div 1</p><div class="removeDiv">Remove X</div></div>
    <div id="donation_element2_row" class="donation_element"><p>
    Div 2</p><div class="removeDiv">Remove X</div></div>
    <div id="donation_element3_row" class="donation_element"><p>
    Div 3</p><div class="removeDiv">Remove X</div></div>
    <div id="donation_element4_row" class="donation_element"><p>
    Div 4</p><div class="removeDiv">Remove X</div></div>
</div>

<div id="addAnother">+ Add Another</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fye8qjk1/11/

Comment: Thank you @JosephCho. I appreciate your words :)

Comment: The only feedback I would have is line 7 and 11 is extra, you don't need it!

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle link.. It was older one!

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. When you remove an item you also need to increment the count down, and add the first div to the list of divs. For example:

```
$('.removeDiv').click( function() {
  $(this).closest('div[id*="donation_element"]').hide();
  count --;
});

$allDivs = $('#donation_element1_row, #donation_element2_row, #donation_element3_row, #donation_element4_row');
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ofw4g2ym/2/

Comment: Thats awesome! I have one question. Because I have the first div displaying on page load, it does not reappear when selecting "add another". Is there a way to do this without hiding that initially? @Joseph Cho

Comment: Sure. You need to account for an edge case where the count is 0, and also add that div to our list of `allDivs`. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ofw4g2ym/2/ Even if you remove the first item it'll reappear.

Comment: This doesnt workd as expected. Add all 4, remove the second one and try to add again.

Comment: Yeah, I was attempting to tweak the code as minimally as possible. There are edge cases it doesn't account for like if a middle div is removed.

Comment: There are edge cases it doesn't account for like if a middle div is removed. Nimitkumar deals with it nicely using something like: https://jsfiddle.net/ofw4g2ym/5/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any counter,
make your code flexible to account for any number of *donation* elements

```js
var $donation = $(".donation");
var $donationAdd = $(".donation-add");
var $donationRemove = $(".donation-remove");
var donationTot = $donation.length;

function donationHandler () {
  if ($donation.filter(":visible").length >= donationTot) {
    $donationAdd.prop("disabled", true);
  }
}

$donationAdd.on("click", function() {
  $donation.filter(":hidden").eq(0).show();
  donationHandler();
});

$donationRemove.on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest(".donation").hide();
  donationHandler();
});
```

```css
*{margin:0; box-sizing:border-box;}

.donation {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.donation ~ .donation{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="donation">
  <p>Div 1</p>
  <button type="button" class="donation-remove">&times; Remove</button>
</div>
<div class="donation">
  <p>Div 2</p>
  <button type="button" class="donation-remove">&times; Remove</button>
</div>
<div class="donation">
  <p>Div 3</p>
  <button type="button" class="donation-remove">&times; Remove</button>
</div>
<div class="donation">
  <p>Div 4</p>
  <button type="button" class="donation-remove">&times; Remove</button>
</div>

<button type="button" class="donation-add">+ Add</button>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```